# how to add space between the amount and unit in c#? e.g., $ 9.00

Tags: c#

I have been trying to add space between the unit and the amount. I have used "c" for currency but that places a $ next to the amount and I want it spaced such that the output can relate to

```
    "Amount:     $    9.00"
    "Total :     $    20.00"
```

I could define it e.g.,

```
Console.WriteLine("{0},{1,5},{2,10:f}", Amount,"$","9");
```

But I want to try it without that so that "c" is used. e.g.,

```
Console.WriteLine("{0},{2:c}",Amount, "9");
```

Comment: What do you want as a result exactly? It is not clear what you asking.

Comment: Output should be the first above.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the currency symbol from the system, but you don't want to use the `:c` formatting option, you could retrieve the symbol yourself.

There is no other way, since `:c` doesn't allow any other formatting options, like padding.

```
Console.WriteLine("{0},{1,5},{2,10:f}"
                 , Amount
                 , System.Globalization.RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.CurrencySymbol
                 ,"9"
                 );
```